# Key code for <> signs for java robot class?

Tags: java, keycode

can you tell me the keycodes for Java Robot class.
For example, to press Enter we use:

```
   a.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   a.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

I want to press these sysmbols `>` and `<` sign. What keyword or code should i use?
Thank you.

Comment: yes they have. As i told them before i can not login to accept. The email associated with my id is random which i don't have access to. Whenever i open this site, by default it shows me as logged in and i cant even aceess my account. SO i just simply ask question.

Comment: Ok i registered it. Its working now but can you answer my question please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean `java.awt.event.KeyInput`, then a quick glance at [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) suggests that `KeyInput.VT_LESS` and `KeyInput.VT_GREATER` would correspond to the `<` and `>` keys.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try VK_LESS, and VK_LESS in combination with SHIFT for  <kbd>></kbd>?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a VK_SHIFT press event, followed by a VK_COMMA press, then a VK_COMMA release and a VK_SHIFT release (assuming QWERTY keyboard). The system will reject a VK_LESS press because that's not a valid key without a shift event.